# Restart IIS hosted application after Application. exit

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, iis-7

I have a web Application which is hosted in local IIS  .To stop application I use Application. Exit command.

But next time I browse the application through local IIS ,it gives me error as "HTTP error 503 ,service is unavailable".

Can I restart by Application. Start or Restart but once it gets exited ,it won't hit method for start or restart command

Is there any other way in IIS to run application after Application.Exit

Comment: Where are you using the Application.Exit command? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Yes Chef7, I have a start and stop methods , on Start i send hex data to port and on stop method i write  Application.Exit command to exit from application.    Now when i hosted the application in IIS , it worked once and after Application.Exit command ,i got error as  HTTP error 503 ,service is unavailable".                                                                                                     So , i need to host application again and again

Comment: Web application should not be stopped. Revise your design please, as it is not a desktop app. I guess you crashed the worker process too many times, and triggered automatic IIS application pool shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

It is unusual and not suggested to stop a website programmatically from within the application itself.  You can schedule AppPool recycles in IIS to reset the site on a schedule or based on memory usage.  This may be what you are looking for.

You could also use the following command from the command line or open a new process:

```
appcmd stop site /site.name: contoso
```

Comment: No chief7 , I have a requirement to exit Application / stop Webiste by System.Environment.Exit(0). Now , how can i restart or start executing a web site hosted in IIS.                                                                                                                    Is there no other solution here to trigger or start website again

Comment: Added a CMD option in my answer.